# Please help me solve

Tags: workflow

I am very much new to latex and when I completed my work I got 15 errors which I cannot sort out.Please help me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Diwali Assignment 2015}
\date{2015-11-10}
\author{Sandeep}

\begin{document}
 \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \maketitle
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}





\section{Diwali Assignment 2015\bfseries}
\label{sec:DiwaliAssignment2015}


\subsection{ATOMIC WASTE DISPOSAL\bfseries}
\label{sec:ATOMICWASTEDISPOSAL}
Radio active waste is mostly hazardous as it poses potential threats to public health or the environment.Therefore radioactive waste management
is very important and has to be taken seriously before it poses a threat to the survival of mankind.
\subparagraph{So Nuclear Regulatory Commission had disposed  radioactive waste material using tightly sealed drums and then dumped into sea which is of 300 ft.NRC is assured of any leaks in drums.But question arrises whether the drum breaks when it hits the ocean floor.Many experiments were conducted on this point and engineers found that the drum breaks when the impact velocity exceeds 40 ft/s  \bfseries}
\paragraph{PROBLEM :\bfseries}
\label{sec:PROBLEM}
Now the problem is to find the impact velocity and check whether it crosses the limiting velocity to prevent any leakage caused due to impact by using the following data
\begin{align*}
    Weight of the drum &= 528 lbs\\
      Volume of the drum &= 7 ft^{3}\\
      density of salt water&= 64 lbs\\
      Drag force of water on Drum,D &= c \times V \frac{(lb)(s)}{ft} where c=0.08\\
      Acceleration due to gravity &= 32.2 \frac{ft}{s^2}
\end{align*}
\newpage

\section{Solving The Problem}
\label{sec:SolvingTheProblem}
This model is solved using 
\subsection{Newton mechanics}
\subsubsection{Newton Mechanics}
\label{sec:NewtonMechanics}

The newton principle we use in this problem is Newton's second law of motion.Using this law we can state that\\ force acting on any object is equal to mass of that body multiplied by acceleration of that body caused due to\\ force acting on it 

i.e,
\begin{align*}
F&=Mass \times Acceleration \\ 
=M \times \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} (1) 
\end{align*}
   as Acceleration,$ a = \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} $
\subparagraph{M,mass of object and y,t denotes displacement and time respectively.}
\subsection{Differential Equations}
\subsubsection{\textbf{SOLUTION:}}
Let direction of increasing y be downwards then weight of the drum W is positive where as buoyant force B and drag force on drum D is negative
Net force F is given by $$ F = W-B-cV (2)$$

 \subsubsection{Formulating Differential Equation :}
 \label{sec:FormulatingDifferentialEquation}

    From (1) and (2) 
      $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{M} (W-B-cV) $$
                                 $$= \frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV) (3)$$          
            where,$W=mass of drum \times acceleration due to gravity$
            i.e, 
                   $$W = m \times g = 528 lbs$$
                    $$B= weight of water displaced$$
                        $$ = volume of drum \times density of salt water$$ 
              $$ = 7 \times 64 $$
                          $$ = 448 lbs$$
On substituting $$ V = \frac{dy}{dt}    in (3) $$
                         $$\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{cg}{W}V = \frac{g}{W}(W-B) (4) $$

    \subsubsection{Solving Differential Equation}
    \label{sec:SolvingDifferentialEquation}

    equation (4) can be written as
    $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{g}{w}(W-B-cV)$$
By variable seperation and integrating we get
$$ \frac{gt}{w} = \int \frac{1}{W-B-cV}dv $$

on solving this equation we get

$$ V(t) = \frac{W-B}{c}[1-\exp(-\frac{cg}{w})t] $$ as V(0) = 0
$From this the limiting value of V(t) i.e when t \rightarrow \infty$ 
$$Velocity = \frac{W-B}{c}
         =\frac{528-448}{0.08}=1000 \frac{ft}{s} $$
This velocity is called Terminal Velocity,which is way greater than limiting impact velocity.
\subparagraph{From this,we cannot conclude as terminal velocity of drum > limting impact velocity to avoid breakage.But drum donot break if terminal velocity<maximum impact velocity}
Therefore,\\
we have to write velocity in terms of displacement\\
i.e $$V(y) instead of V(t)$$

\subparagraph{To write V in terms of displacement y}
$$From equation (4)$$

        $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{g}{w}(W-B-cV)$$
using chain derivative rule $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dv}{dy} (5)$
substituting in (4)

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt} \times \frac{dv}{dy}&=\frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV)\\
as \frac{dy}{dt} &= V,\\
&\Rightarrow V\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV)\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{V}{W-B-cV}dv&=\frac{g}{W}dy (By variable separation)
\end{align*}

 On integrating both sides,\\
$$\Rightarrow \frac{gy}{W} = \int{\frac{vdv}{W-B-cV}}$$\\
          Taking -c as common and substitute \\
                    $$\frac{W-B}{c} = K$$
      \begin{align*} 
                                                &=-\frac{1}{c}\int{\frac{V-K+K dv}{V-k}}\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{gy}{W} = -\frac{1}{c}[V-K\ln(V-K)]$
\end{align*}
   Therefore,   \\                                  
           \frac{gy}{W} = \frac{(B-W)\ln(1+\frac{cV}{B-W})-cV}{c^2}


By substituting the values of g,y,W,B,c we get the value of Impact Velocity V
However to approximately calculate this value,
we assume that c is negligible and tends towards zero and calculate the limit when c tends towards zero in R.H.S

\subsubsection{Calculating limit of R.H.S when c tends towards 0}
\label{sec:CalculatingLimitOfRHSwhenctendstowards0}

    $$\lim_{c \to 0} \frac{(B-W)\ln(1+\frac{cV}{B-W})-cV{c^2}$$
    As this is in the form \frac{0}{0}
    $By using L'Hospital's Rule and simplifying
                 = \frac{V^2}{2(W-B)}$ \\
$\Rightarrow \frac{gy}{w} = \frac{V^2}{2(W-B)}$ \\
Hence $V = [\frac{2g}{W}(W-B)y]^\frac{1}{2}$\\
By substituting,\\
$$V= \sqrt{2927.2727272727}$$\\
      $$\approx 54.1042764$$
\section{CONCLUSION}
\label{sec:CONCLUSION}
\paragraph{Here,We got that the Impact velocity of drum > limiting velocity of drum.Hence there is a very chance of leaking if the drum hits the seabed}
Using above results we can find velocity of any object falling through a denser medium at any time or at any place having this drag force

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! There's a `$` inside an `align*` environment (l.115), immediately after there are `$...$` missing (l.118), you have a `\frac{(B-W)...` that is missing a closing brace (l.128) and you have a `\frac{0}{0}` outside of math mode (l.129). <= fixing these will at least make the errors go away – there are other things that could be improved, too…

Comment: If you want to get the correct enumeration of the document structure, then you should use the right order, and use `\subsubsection`and `\paragraph` before use a subparagraph. But if you don't, then you can use the starred version instead.

Comment: A good practice, not only for beginners, is to compile before you write so many lines. It will help you find out where errors are.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I try to rewrite your (not)MWE, however I gave up somewhere after its middle ... It is to time consuming to understand your code, your intend etc. I hope, that this fragment will show you how to write math text, use different math environment provided by `amsmath`, I'm very sure that formation of your text can be further improved, however this task I left to you :-)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm,a4paper]{geometry}

    \title{Diwali Assignment 2015}
    \date{2015-11-10}
    \author{Sandeep}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Diwali Assignment 2015}
\label{sec:DiwaliAssignment2015}

\subsection{ATOMIC WASTE DISPOSAL}
\label{sec:ATOMICWASTEDISPOSAL}
Radio active waste is mostly hazardous as it poses potential threats to public health or the environment. Therefore radioactive waste management
is very important and has to be taken seriously before it poses a threat to the survival of mankind.

\emph{So Nuclear Regulatory Commission had disposed  radioactive waste material using tightly sealed drums and then dumped into sea which is of 300 ft. NRC is assured of any leaks in drums.But question arises whether the drum breaks when it hits the ocean floor.Many experiments were conducted on this point and engineers found that the drum breaks when the impact velocity exceeds 40 ft/s}

\paragraph{PROBLEM}
\label{sec:PROBLEM}
The problem is to find the impact velocity and check whether it crosses the limiting velocity to prevent any leakage caused due to impact by using the following data:
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
weight of the drum              & 528 lbs  \\
volume of the drum              & 7 $ft^{3}$\\
density of salt water           & 64 lbs\\
drag force of water on Drum     & D = $c \times V \frac{(lb)(s)}{ft}$ where $c=0.08$\\
Acceleration due to gravity     & $32.2 \frac{ft}{s^2}$
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\newpage

\section{Solving The Problem}
\label{sec:SolvingTheProblem}
This model is solved by using \textbf{Newton mechanics}.

\subsection{Newton Mechanics}
\label{sec:NewtonMechanics}
The Newton principle we use in this problem is Newton's second law of motion. Using this law we can state that force acting on any object is equal to mass of that body multiplied by acceleration of that body caused due to force acting on i.e,
    \begin{align}
F   & = Mass \times Acceleration    \notag\\
    & = M \times \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} \label{eq:1}
    \end{align}
as Acceleration, $a = \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$. 
In \eqref{eq:1} $M$, mass of object and $y,t$ denotes displacement and time respectively.

\subsection{Differential Equations}
\paragraph{\textbf{SOLUTION:}}
Let direction of increasing y be downwards then weight of the drum W is positive where as buoyant force B and drag force on drum D is negative
Net force F is given by
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
F = W-B-cV 
    \end{equation}

\subsubsection{Formulating Differential Equation :}
\label{sec:FormulatingDifferentialEquation}
From \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}
    \begin{align}
\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} 
    & = \frac{1}{M} (W-B-cV)            \notag
    & = \frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV) \label{eq:3}
    \end{align}
where $W$ is mass of drum $\times$ acceleration due to gravity, i.e.,
    \begin{align*}
W & = m \times g = 528 lbs\\
B & = \text{weight of water displaced}\\
  & = \text{volume of drum $\times$ density of salt water}\\
  & = 7 \times 64 = 448 lbs
  \end{align*}
On substituting $V=\frac{dy}{dt}$  in \eqref{eq:3} follows
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
\frac{dV}{dt} + \frac{cg}{W} V = \frac{g}{W}(W-B) 
    \end{equation}

    \subsubsection{Solving Differential Equation}
    \label{sec:SolvingDifferentialEquation}
Equation\eqref{eq:4} can be written as
    \[
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{g}{w}(W-B-cV)
    \]
By variable seperation and integrating we get
    \[
\frac{gt}{w} = \int \frac{1}{W-B-cV}dv
    \]
on solving this equation we get
    \[
V(t) = \frac{W-B}{c}[1-\exp(-\frac{cg}{w})t] 
    \quad\text{as } V(0) = 0
    \]
From this the limiting value of $V(t)$ i.e when $t \rightarrow \infty$
    \begin{align*}
Velocity & = \frac{W-B}{c}
         & = \frac{528-448}{0.08} =1 000 \frac{ft}{s} 
    \end{align*}
This velocity is called Terminal Velocity, which is way greater than limiting impact velocity.

\emph{From this,we cannot conclude as terminal velocity of drum $>$ limting impact velocity to avoid breakage.But drum don't break if terminal velocity $<$ maximum impact velocity}
Therefore, we have to write velocity in terms of displacement\\
i.e $V(y)$ instead of $V(t)$.

\subsubsection{To write $V$ in terms of displacement $y$}
From equation \eqref{eq:4} 
    \[
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{g}{w}(W-B-cV)
    \]
using chain derivative rule 
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dv}{dy}
    \end{equation}
substituting in \eqref{eq:4}
    \begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt} \times \frac{dv}{dy}
    & = \frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV)
\intertext{as $\frac{dy}{dt} = V$}
    & \Rightarrow V\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{g}{W}(W-B-cV)\\
    & \Rightarrow \frac{V}{W-B-cV}dv\\
    & =\frac{g}{W}dy \text{ (By variable separation)}
    \end{align*}
By integrating both sides:
    \begin{align*}
\frac{gy}{W} 
    & = \int{\frac{vdv}{W-B-cV}}
\intertext{Taking $-c$ as common and substitute $\frac{W-B}{c} = K$}
    & = -\frac{1}{c}\int{\frac{V-K+K dv}{V-k}} 
        \Rightarrow \frac{gy}{W}\\
    & = -\frac{1}{c}[V-K\ln(V-K)]
\intertext{Therefore}   
\frac{gy}{W} 
    & = \frac{(B-W)\ln(1+\frac{cV}{B-W})-cV}{c^2}
    \end{align*}

etc
\end{document}
```

Main problems of your code are described in comments to your question. According to them, I partially change your use of use of `paragraph` and `subparagraph` as they aren't intended for emphasizing of text, and try to made some consistency in use of `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection`. However, since the structure of your document is still not clear to me, probably I miss many things.

Regarding of use `$$ ... $$`: I omit this, since it is not LaTeX notation. I replace them with `\[ ... \]` or other LaTeX/AMS math environments.

To see how the text looks after my proposed changes, just compile above code. It gives four page of text.

I hope that my reformatting will help you somehow.

Comment: Please stop feeding the vampires.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, :-) I will, I exhaust myself (read: stay out of blood) to much. So, for while I'm without power ...  Well, at this ask I remember myself, how I wrote my firsts latex texts ... and have been happy if someone been willing to help me.

Comment: @Texty, if my answer is of any help to you, you can accept them (if this is now possible). Happy TeXing!